Mocking Kendo UI for jQuery modules using jasmine
i am new to Kendo UI for jQuery and trying to write unit tests to a class which is something like below.
define('abc', [], () => {
 const listOfFunctions = {
   formatName(name) {
       return name.toUppercase();
    };
    return listOfFunctions;
   }
});

So far what i learned is that Jasmine pairs well with Kendo UI for jQuery in writing unit test cases and as part of that i learnt that the functions which are exported can be only tested.
I did not find any right articles that would explain on how to test the methods inside the abc module.
Can any one of you recommend or point to an example that would help me in writing the unit test cases .
So far i have looked into below links.

jasmine.github.io/index.html
Mocking dependent modules using Jasmine


please share a sample function you want to test and the code tried,

Thanks for the reply Naren. I have already posted the sample function in the question and the code which i tried is as below.

import { utililites }   from "../filelocation";   describe("test utils function", () { it("format username", function() { let a = utilities.formatName("optimusprime"); expect(a).toBe("OPTIMUSPRIME")})})
